# Use specific form in view, based on chosen option

Tags: django, django-forms

I am writing web-application for Hydrological observation. **There are different types of Hydroposts. Hydroposts are classified by observations they are making.**

1. HydropostType1 observes water level, water temperature, air temperature, discharge
2. HydropostType2 observes water level, water temperature, air temperature
3. HydropostType3 observes water level, water temperature, water ripple

and so on.

My forms.py looks like that

**forms.py**

```
#Minimum forms for observation
class BasicObservationForm(forms.Form):
    level = forms.IntegerField(label = 'Уровень воды')
    water_temperature = forms.DecimalField(label = 'Температура воды',
            max_digits = 5, 
            decimal_places = 2, 
            max_value = 70, 
            min_value = -70,
            required = False)

class AirTemperatureForm(forms.Form):
    air_temperature = forms.DecimalField(label = 'Температура воздуха', required = False)

class RippleForm(forms.Form):
    ripple = forms.IntegerField(label = 'Волнения воды', required = False)

class DischargeForm(forms.Form):
    discharge = forms.DecimalField(label = 'Расход воды', required = False)

class PrecipitationForm(forms.Form):
    precipitation = forms.CharField(label = 'Атмосферные осадки', required = False)



class Hydropost1CategoryForm(BasicObservationForm, AirTemperatureForm, DischargeForm):
    pass


class Hydropost2CategoryForm(BasicObservationForm, AirTemperatureForm):
    pass


class Hydropost3CategoryForm(BasicObservationForm, AirTemperatureForm, RippleForm):
    pass
```

Right now I am using multiple views for each category form.

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url = '/login/')
def Hydropost1CategoryRecord(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Hydropost1CategoryForm()
        context = { 'form': form, }
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('/')
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form = Hydropost1CategoryForm()
        context = { 'form' : form, }
    return render(request, 'hydrology/record.html', context)

@login_required(login_url = '/login/')
def Hydropost2CategoryRecord(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Hydropost2CategoryForm()
        context = { 'form': form, }
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('/')
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form = Hydropost2CategoryForm()
        context = { 'form' : form, }
    return render(request, 'hydrology/record.html', context)
```

And I create view for each hydropost category

record.html is just holding forms.

```
{{ form }}
```

As result I need multiple urls for each form type

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name = 'home'),
    path('hp1record/', views.Hydropost1CategoryRecord, name = 'hp1record'),
    path('hp2record/', views.Hydropost2CategoryRecord, name = 'hp2record'),
    path('category/', views.search_hydropost_type, name = 'category'),
]
```

I identify hydropost category on my home page and redirects to necessary hydropost url.
I tried if elif by POST hydropost category to view, but it creates a hard readable view, because I have several types of hydroposts.

My home view just renders html with Javascript. All job is done by javascript

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url = '/login/')
def home(request):
    user = request.user
    hydrologist = Hydrologist.objects.get(user = user)
    hydroposts = hydrologist.hydropost_set.all()
    context = { 'hydroposts' : hydroposts ,}
    return render(request, 'hydrology/home.html', context)
```

hydrology.js

```
var category;
var url_category = {% url 'category' %};
var url_hp1record = {% url 'hp1record' %};
var url_hp2record = {% url 'hp2record' %};

//I get hydropost type using another search_category_view
$('[name="hydropost"]').change(function () {
     hydropost = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
          url: url_category,
          type: 'GET',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
                'hydropost': hydropost
          },
          success: function(data){ 
                category = data.category;
                $( "h3" ).replaceWith( "<h3>" + data.category + "</h3>" );
          },
          error: function(data){
                $( "h3" ).replaceWith( "<h3>" + data.hydropost + "</h3>");
          }
      });
});

$('[name="hydropost"]').trigger("change") //first page load

$('.btn').click(function() {
    hydropost = $('select option:selected').val();
    //Here I compare category, I am using bootstrap modal
    //I load html from url
    if (category == 'пост 1 разряд') {
        $(".modal-body").load(String(url_hp1record));
    } else if (category == 'пост 2 разряд') {
        $(".modal-body").load(String(url_hp2record));
    }
});
```

**Is there any other ways to use one view for each hydropost, or one url for each hydropost**

Comment: can you update your question with your home page ? how are you identifying hydropost category ?

Comment: you said **I tried if elif by POST hydropost category to view, but it creates a hard readable view** did you mean to say that you created a single view ?

Comment: Yes I did, for every if case I created different Form and also I should add is form isvalid, figure out GET or POST. It looks like merged version of Hydropost1CategoryRecord view and Hydropost2CategoryRecord view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have one general view which takes an input as a type of the form (i.e `1` for `Hydropost1CategoryForm` or `2` for `Hydropost2CategoryForm`) . This type of form variable is send form ajax to your general view on `POST` or on `GET`.

You can then use this information ( Type of form ) to select a particular `Form` from a dictionary containing these forms. Here is an example:

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...      
    # url for general view which handles all your forms in one place
    url(r'HydropostCategoryRecord/$', views.HydropostCategoryRecord),       
    ...
]
```

views.py:

```
form_list = {'1': Hydropost1CategoryForm, '2': Hydropost2CategoryFrom}    

@login_required(login_url = '/login/')
def HydropostCategoryRecord(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       h_type = str(request.POST.get('h_type'))   
       form = form_list[h_type](request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          return redirect('/')
    elif request.method == 'GET':
         h_type = str(request.GET.get('h_type'))
         form_ref = form_list[h_type]()
context = { 'key' : value, }   
return render(request, 'hydrology/record.html', context)
```

As you can see I didn't have to define `if`, `elif` for every single form because I am using a dictionary which takes input as the form number (i.e `1` in `Hydropost1CategoryForm` or `2` in `Hydropost2CategoryForm`) and gives me the output as the form name.

Comment: Thank you! What is second empty string after HydropostCategoryForm?

Comment: @YesDslv Its just another member of a tuple. Look at my answer I removed that empty string :) but you must have to have a comma after the first element of tuple just to tell the interpreter that I am using a tuple. :)

Comment: or you simply have a dictionary with values as your class name. Edit my answer check it out. It looks much better now.